# What does "cordova run android" does?

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

Does it run `cordova build android` then install the APK onto the device / emulator?

If  not, what does it really do?
I've tried searching for more details on cordova documentation site but to no avail.

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're pretty much right. Citing from the [Cordova CLI reference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#cordova-run-command):

The run command ...

> Prepares, builds, and deploys app on specified platform
>   devices/emulators. If a device is connected it will be used, unless an
>   eligible emulator is already running.

Comment: Thanks. Urgh. I guess I missed that part.